# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 with BitLocker enabled

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Is it possible to leave BitLocker enabled and not have to enter the BitLocker key in each time I want to start Windows from Grub? I really do not want to disable BitLocker, but it is a pain to enter the key each time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Full Disk Encryption (Linux) or BitLocker (Windows) requires that you enter the key to unlock the disk. If they key was stored somewhere on disk it would defeat the purpose of using disk encryption.